# Understanding semivariogram model in ArcGIS; difference between Binned points and Average points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst

I am sorry if I am unaware of some very basic ideas of semivariogram. I am trying to understand the difference between binned points and averaged points. In this [document] (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/fitting-a-model-to-the-empirical-semivariogram.htm)! it says

> Binned values are shown as red dots, and are generated by grouping
>   (binning) empirical semivariogram/covariance points together using
>   square cells that are one lag wide. Average points are shown as blue
>   crosses, and are generated by binning empirical
>   semivariogram/covariance points that fall within angular sectors.

I am not sure what it means by:

> fall within angular sectors.

Can you clarify this?

Comment: see [GeoNet: Semivariogram](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/10326)